# Redux-saga is fetching data but is not updating the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I used axios within redux-saga to fetch some data. I did `console.log()` in every step to see result at every step. Even I'm successfully able to print the whole fetched data on the console, **the only thing is that it is not updating the state** as the screen output is blank and in DevTools I see the state is empty.

My *actions*:

```
export const listSearchBrewery = ( ) => {     // gets workerSaga to fetch the data
    return {
        type: LIST_SEARCH_BREWERY_REQUEST,
    };
};

export const listSetBrewerySuccess = ( breweries ) =>{    // updates the store and also for display
    return {
        type: SET_LIST_BREWERY_SUCCESS,
        breweries
    };
};
```

My *reducers*:

```
const initialState = {
    breweries: [],
}

const ListBreweryReducer = ( state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case types.listSearchBrewery:
            return { ...state };
        case types.listSetBrewerySuccess:
            return { ...state, breweries: action.breweries };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

My *saga*:

```
export function* watcherSaga() {
    yield takeLatest("LIST_SEARCH_BREWERY_REQUEST", workerSaga);
}

function fetchBreweryList() {
    return axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries'
    });
}

function* workerSaga() {
    try{
        console.log("Entered worker saga.");
        const response = yield call(fetchBreweryList);
        const breweries = response.data;
        console.log("worker-saga executed.");

        yield put({ type: "SET_LIST_BREWERY_SUCCESS", breweries });
        console.log("store set");
        console.log(breweries[0]);        // successfully printing on the console
    }
    catch (error) {
        yield put({ type: "SET_BREWERY_ERROR", error });
    }
}
```

Finally my *component*:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { listSearchBrewery } from '../actions/index';

const ListBrewery = ( props ) => {
    const { brewery, getBreweryList} = props;

    return (
        <div className="Container">
                <button className="button" onClick={getBreweryList}>Brewerries</button>
            <div className="list">
                {brewery.map((item) => (
                    <div key={item.id}>
                        <p>{item.name} in {item.city}</p>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        brewery: state.breweries,
        //error: state.error
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    getBreweryList: () => dispatch(listSearchBrewery()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ListBrewery);
```

In DevTools I can see `SET_LIST_BREWERY_SUCCESS` action is dispatching through saga and is getting all the data:
[image: action-fetcching-data]

But the state is empty:
[image: empty-state]

I can't understand where is the mistake!

Comment: What is the value of `types.listSetBrewerySuccess`?

Comment: Things look fine. If you put your code to codesanbox, it would easy to figure out the issue.

Comment: @rayhatfield it's the complete array response.

Comment: Your reducer is looking for an action with `type: types.listSetBrewerySuccess`. It doesn’t make sense for that to be “the complete array response”.

Comment: What needs to be changed? It's confusing. Say, for every ID, I want to fetch name, city, state.?

Comment: Your action has a type: `type: SET_LIST_BREWERY_SUCCESS`. Your reducer does not have a handler for `SET_LIST_BREWERY_SUCCESS`. So unless `types.setListBrewerySuccess` equals the value of `SET_LIST_BREWERY_SUCCESS` your reducer isn’t going to handle this action.

Comment: But I have provided reducer for that action. It's `listSetBrewerySuccess()` for `SET_LIST_BREWERY_SUCCESS`.  Your function has `List` **after** `set`, but in mine `list` is **before** `Set`. I should have named it `setList...` for clarity.